# What is the best logic to search available room in room scheduling system base on case below using javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

I have problem to make logic to complete my scheduling system.

Case :

1. I have room schedule from :

   > 07:00 - 15:00
2. From room schedule above I already have booking list like below :

   > 08:00 - 10:00
   >
   > 10:00 - 11:00
   >
   > 12:00 - 15:00
3. The result I want is :

   > 07:00 - 08:00 -> Available
   >
   > 08:00 - 10:00 -> Booked
   >
   > 10:00 - 11:00 -> Booked
   >
   > 11:00 - 12:00 -> Available
   >
   > 12:00 - 15:00 -> Booked

Does anyone ever had a case like this before? 
Any idea or suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the available slots from start to end of roomAvailable.
I have added comments at possible places.

```js
var roomAvailable = {
  start: "07:00",
  end: "15:00"
}
// gets numeric value of time
var getValue = function(time) {
  var arr = time.split(":");
  var val = arr[0] * 60 + arr[1] * 1;
  return val;
}
//converts to readable time string
var toTimeString = function(val) {
  var hr = Math.floor(val / 60);
  var min = val % 60;
  if (hr < 10) hr = "0" + hr;
  if (min < 10) min = "0" + min;
  return hr + ":" + min;
}

var booked = [{
    start: "08:00",
    end: "10:30"
  },
  {
    start: "10:40",
    end: "11:00"
  },
  {
    start: "12:00",
    end: "15:00"
  }
];

var printSlot = function(a, b) {
  console.log(toTimeString(a) + " - " + toTimeString(b));
}

var getAvailableSlots = function(roomAvailable, booked) {
  //sort booked slots by start time [Optional]
  var bookedSorted = booked.sort(function(a, b) {
    var x = getValue(a.start);
    var y = getValue(b.start);

    if (x < y) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (x > y) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  var bookingStart = getValue(roomAvailable.start);
  var bookingEnd = getValue(roomAvailable.end);
  //now start from bookingStart
  var oStart = bookingStart;
  var i = 0;
  while (oStart < bookingEnd) {
    if (i < booked.length) {
      if (oStart < getValue(booked[i].start)) {
        printSlot(oStart, getValue(booked[i].start));
      }
      //has to be equal 
      oStart = getValue(booked[i].end);
      i++;
    } else {
      //left out time..
      if (oStart < bookingEnd) {
        printSlot(oStart, bookingEnd);
      }
    }
  }

};

getAvailableSlots(roomAvailable, booked);
```

Comment: excellent @Sunil,
yours is better and shorter then mine 
thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it largely depends on how your booking data is currently structured, but my first thought would be to assemble an array of time segments and mark them accordingly.

eg if your shortest booking is 1 hour, then a day has 8 sessions:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Applying the current bookings would result in:

```
[0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]
```

When you generate the availability list you would concatenate the contiguous values.

Answer (score 0):

I come back with my result, implement idea from @lecstor,

full source code :

```
exports.exprocedure = function(req,res){
var minT = 7;
var maxT = 15;
var arraySession = [];

//Booked Time
//08:00 - 10:00
//10:00 - 11:00
//12:00 - 15:00
var arrayBookingPerTrans    = [{start:8,finish:10},{start:10,finish:11},{start:12,finish:15}];
var arrayBookPerHour        = [];
var avSession               = [];

//split session
for(var i = minT; i < maxT; i++)
{
    arraySession.push({
        start:i,
        finish:i+1
    });
}
console.log("Session :");
console.log(arraySession);

//split booked time
for(var a=0;a<arrayBookingPerTrans.length;a++)
{
    for(var j = arrayBookingPerTrans[a].start; j < arrayBookingPerTrans[a].finish; j++)
    {
        arrayBookPerHour.push({
            start:j,
            finish:j+1,
            Trans:a
        })
    }
}
console.log("Booking Per Hour :");
console.log(arrayBookPerHour);

//filter to find available time
var avSession  = arraySession.filter(function(array_el){
    return arrayBookPerHour.filter(function(anotherOne_el)
    {
        return anotherOne_el.start == array_el.start;
    }).length == 0
});

console.log("Available :");
console.log(avSession);

//push available time and booked time in an array
var allArray = [];
var sum = avSession.length + arrayBookingPerTrans.length;
for(var i=0;i<avSession.length;i++)
{
    allArray.push({
        start  : avSession[i].start,
        finish : avSession[i].finish,
        state  : 'Available'
    });
}

for(var i=0;i<arrayBookingPerTrans.length;i++)
{
    allArray.push({
        start  : arrayBookingPerTrans[i].start,
        finish : arrayBookingPerTrans[i].finish,
        state  : 'Booked'
    });
}

//sorting 
function compare(a, b) {
    const startA = a.start
    const startB = b.start

    let comparison = 0;
    if (startA > startB) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (startA < startB) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return comparison;
}

  console.log("RESULT SORTING");
  console.log(allArray.sort(compare));

res.json({ 
    result      :'success',
    content     : allArray 
});}
```

Result :

```
Available Time :
[ { start: 7, finish: 8 }, { start: 11, finish: 12 } ]

RESULT SORTING : 
[{start: 7, finish: 8, state: 'Available' },
{ start: 8, finish: 10, state: 'Booked' },
{ start: 10, finish: 11, state: 'Booked' },
{ start: 11, finish: 12, state: 'Available' },
{ start: 12, finish: 15, state: 'Booked' } ]
```